# Merging two log4j.properties files

Tags: java, properties, log4j

I have two classes and two log4j.properties files: a file for each class. Everything is working fine. Now I want to merge the two properties files into one. But I still want each class to have its own log file. How do I do that? I did the following but it's not working: class Abc.java logs fine, but Xyz.java does not log to its own file anymore. Note that Xyz.java gets a dynamic log filename.

```
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.     log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

 log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.File=/opt/mysite/var/log/allhere.error.log
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.MaxFileSize=4MB
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
 log4j.appender.ABC_ERR_LOG.Threshold = WARN

 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG.File=/opt/mysite/var/log/allhere.log
 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG.MaxFileSize=8MB
 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.ABC_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG=org.apache.     log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG.File=/opt/mysite/var/log/job-${logfilename}.log
 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG.MaxFileSize=8MB
 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG.layout=org.apache.     log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.XYZ_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

 log4j.logger.com.mysite=DEBUG, ABC_LOG, ABC_ERR_LOG, XYZ_LOG
```

Answer (score 1):

your two classes are in the same package ?

If not, you can have to logger :

```
log4j.logger.com.mysite.packageAbc=DEBUG, ABC_LOG, ABC_ERR_LOG
log4j.logger.com.mysite.packageXyz=DEBUG, XYZ_LOG
```

Otherwise you can set dynamically log file like this :

```
public final void initParams(final String logFileName,
        final Layout logLayout, final boolean origin, final Level level) {
    FileAppender appender =
        (FileAppender) logger.getParent().getAppender(DEFAULT_APPENDER_NAME);

    if (appender != null && !logFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(appender.getFile())) {
        appender.setFile(logFileName);
        appender.setThreshold(level);
        appender.setLayout(logLayout);
        appender.activateOptions();
    }
}
```

The important part is the

```
 appender.activateOptions();
```

so that log4j reload its configuration

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my properties file was correct. There was something wrong with my file system.